# vim displaying live formula without document body

Tags: vim, latex

I know there is a plugin called `vim-live-latex-preview`, which also requires a root tex file with `\begin{document}\end{document}` body.
What I need is actually when I type in a formula in a tex file with vim, there could be some live display rendering the formula as I typed, just like the R studio notebook.

An easy hack I could think up of is to automatically insert the formula I typed into a `\begin{document}\end{document}` body, but I actually do not know how to do that. Any suggestions? ideas?

Comment: Isn't compiling the source file enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one solution is to wrap around document around pdflatex with the bare math latex file to show quickly if the formula displays good